# How to export multiple worksheets to CSV (without saving over the current worksheet)

Tags: excel, vba, csv

I'm trying to export a number of worksheets in my workbook to .csv via some code like this:

```
Sub Export_To_CSV(exportPath As String)    

    Dim filePath As String 

    For Each WS In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets

            filePath = exportPath & "(" & WS.Name & ").dat"
            WS.SaveAs Filename:=filePath, FileFormat:=xlCSV

    Next 
End Sub
```

The problem is that this saves over the current .xlsm file that I have open.

How can I get it to export the .csv without changing the name of the current file?

I thought `SaveCopyAs` would do the trick,  but it only applies to a `workbook` and not a `worksheet`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here comes my idea which could help you...
Add this part of code instead you current `for...next` section:

```
'...your code here
Dim tmpWS As Worksheet
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
For Each WS In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets

        filePath = exportPath & "(" & WS.Name & ").dat"

        WS.Copy
        Set tmpWS = ActiveSheet
        tmpWS.SaveAs Filename:=filePath, FileFormat:=xlCSV
        tmpWS.Parent.Close False
Next
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
'...your code here
```

Logic of the code? First, it makes a copy of your sheet into temporary workbook, next it saves new sheet as CSV file and finally, it closes temporary workbook. Moreover, I added `Application.DisplayAlerts` instructions that your code overwrites `.csv` file without asking if file already exists.

Comment: I was preparing this same answer as the most convenient one, so +1

Comment: That's fantastic. Good thinking to let give it a temporary workbook rather than trying to stop `SaveAs` from doing what it wants to do!

Answer (score 0):

You could also first save the workbook, then save off the worksheets and finally close the workbook without having to save (again):

```
' ... your code here
    ActiveWorkbook.Save
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False

Dim WS As Worksheet

For Each WS In Worksheets
        Filepath = "c:\temp\" & WS.Name & ".dat"
        WS.SaveAs Filename:=Filepath, FileFormat:=xlCSV, _
        CreateBackup:=False
Next
    ActiveWorkbook.Close
' ... your code here
```